# *ngFor not executing when using variable from the module in ionic/angular project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic/Angular application and I want to display values from a list inside a  statement using *ngFor. But for some reason *ngFor does nothing.

*ngFor does not run when I say `*ngFor="let i of eventList"` but does run when I place the values the variable has inside

```
*ngFor="let i of {'id': 1, 'name':'Superman'},{'id' :2,'name':'Batman'},
  {'id' : 5, 'name':'BatGirl'},
  {'id' : 3, 'name':'Robin'},
  {'id' : 4, 'name':'Flash'}
];"
```

then it runs.

Here is my tab1.module.ts and html

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { AuthService} from '../auth.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule
{ 
  public eventList: {'id': number, 'name': string}[]  =[{'id': 1, 'name':'Superman'},
  {'id' : 2, 'name':'Batman'},
  {'id' : 5, 'name':'BatGirl'},
  {'id' : 3, 'name':'Robin'},
  {'id' : 4, 'name':'Flash'}
];
  public message: any = '';
  constructor(public auth: AuthService)
  { 
  } 
}
```

The html

```
<ion-item >
  <ion-input type="number" clearInput></ion-input>
    <ion-select placeholder="Select One" >
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let i of eventList" value="{{i.id}}">
          {{i.name}}
       </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

When I run this the select box stays empty. I have tried many different ways and formatting for the variable as well and it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your logic inside your `Tab1PageComponent` not on module itself.

The module is for declaring dependencies, exporting components, etc. It almost always remains empty.

Comment: A silly mistake. I did not see there is a tab1.page.ts file. Thank you good sir @Elias Soares

Answer (score 2):

Place the code in your component and not in the modules. [Angular modules](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules) is majorly for imports, exports, declarations etc.